# Need to change page title in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors, coding-style

I need to change the page title.
The page is created by using a category link. So I need to change the page title to "News"
I checked the customization. but I can't change the Text.
So I need Custom CSS for that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOoHn.png)

Comment: Please expand on your issue and the things you have tried. Titles can be changed in WordPress easily.

Comment: An image is not enough for us to be able to help. Please include enough HTML (and relevant CSS) for us to see what may be required. You can find the HTML/CSS by using your browser's devtools inspect facility. However, this question may be better answered as a Wordpress specific one.

Comment: <h1 class="page-title">Category: <span>News</span></h1>

This is the code used in that page title
I need to change that Page title
Category: News to "News"

Comment: https://ibros-dev.com/category/news/

Comment: Try this, You can extend the get_the_archive_title filter https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179590/185919

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score -1):

you can get more information about change title on wordpress in this page:
https://mekshq.com/change-site-title-wordpress/

Regards.

Comment: The original question is asking about the page title, not the site title like the article linked is instructing on.